# Grouping millions of binary files in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2

Im looking for some guidance on potentially grouping millions of files using Spark

I have around 1.5m files per day, ranging from just a few kb to 2gb in size. Right now, Spark struggles to handle this many small files, plus the data skew is huge. Another problem i have involves the messages inside not being the same size and the only way to determine that is by reading the first n bytes.

I have been thinking about writing an application in Spark that can zip through these files and aggregate them into equal sized binary files. Im just not sure how to configure spark to do such a thing.

Comment: As I know, there is no really good solution for this.  The environment works well with fewer really large files rather than lots and lots of smaller files.  Hopefully someone will just in with a working solution, but at this point in time, I don't think you have many options, or any.

Comment: The solution we have right now is to group all the files into equally sized tarballs and process those. That works quite well but there's an added overhead of having to do that. Currently we use a solidatory Python script for this, it might be a good usecase for MapReduce